# Why should I create File object and then use it in FileWriter or PrintWriter when I can create file with latter ones?

Tags: java, stream, java-io, filewriter

Why:

```
File file = new File("somefile.txt");
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
```

When we can directly:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("somefile.txt");
```

I understand the concept and understand that File() constructor creates an abstraction of the file, but putting this down to practical problems, why one should want to create File object and then pass it to the FileWriter? (or any other writer constructor)

What is the purpose?

Comment: Because a `String` doesn't necessarily convey that it's meant to be used to represent a file name. A `File` (and `Path` more recently), however, exists exactly for that reason.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? so you say about string passed to the File constructor.. what are other purposes? I didn't get it..

Comment: Because **you're misunderstanding what the `File` object is**. It is *not* the file on the file system. It is simply a wrapper/helper class for working with file *paths*, i.e. qualified file names. "Creating" a `File` object does *not* create a file on the file system. Read the javadoc of [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html): *An abstract representation of file and directory **pathnames**.*

Comment: The method is just *overloaded*. It is mainly there to provide the user a more comfortable way of using the `PrintWriter`. If you have your file currently as `File` object, you can directly pass it; if you have it as `InputStream`, you can use that; if you have a `String` representing the path, just use that. Internally they all break down to the same method which opens an `InputStream` to the ressource.

Comment: @Andreas, I perfectly understand what you're saying and the fact that it's not creating physical object on the disk has nothing to do with my question.. it's you who didn't understands my question.

Comment: @Zabuza, that's what I thought. Deep down, they implement same logic.. but I was thinking, maybe abstraction through FIle object can have some more insights? Sure, I understand that if I have any whatsoever representation of file, I can pass it.. but question is when I am about to create it.. and I have nothing.. like I'm asking in the title of question :)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri The phrasing of the question title makes it sound like you think creating a `File` object creates the file on the file system. *"when I can **create file** with latter ones?"* reads as "opposed to creating the file with the `File` object". Whether using `File` or `String` as parameter to `FileWriter`, it is the `FileWriter` that creates the file on the file system, not the `File` object.

Comment: "Why should I create File object *and then use it* in FileWriter or PrintWriter when I can create file with latter ones? - was my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the two versions do the same thing.  The only real difference is code readability.  (It is up to you to decide which version you think is more readable.)

On the other hand, if you need to perform manipulations on the file pathnames, it is better to use `File` or `Path` to do that rather than trying to do the same thing using string bashing.  Examples include getting a parent directory path, forming a child directory path, adding or removing filename suffixes.  By using `File` or `Path`, you can often avoid complications such as platform specific differences in pathname syntax.

In addition, `File` and `Path` (and related classes) allow you to do other things on the files / directories themselves.  For example, renaming / moving, deleting or testing and changing permissions.

In short, in *other* cases there may be good reasons to prefer using `File`, etcetera.  But in your example it makes no real difference.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen C! Good and normal answer.

Comment: Your comment is off-topic for this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a convenience. Check the source code for the constructors. (Open JDK implementation)

```
public PrintWriter(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName))), false);
}
```

---

```
public FileOutputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(name != null ? new File(name) : null, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method is just *overloaded*. It is mainly there to provide the user a more comfortable way of using the `PrintWriter`.

If you have your file currently as `File` object, you can directly pass it.
If you have it as `OutputStream`, you can use that.
If you have a `String` representing the path, just use that and so on.

Internally they all break down to the same method which opens an `OutputStream` to the ressource.

Imagine you do not create the ressource by yourself but rather get it as object from **another method**. If the method returns a `File` object and `PrintWriter` would not have this additional constructor, you would need to extract the *path* from the file object. That is one extra line of code and computer scientists are lazy...

Also the main constructor would be the one that uses the `OutputStream` as this is the most flexible object, it also allows printing to stuff that is no file like a web ressource or other streams.
If you now just want to write some lines into a file the additional constructors are pretty handy and save some lines of code.

If you just want to create a new file at a given location on your file system, sure why not use the `new PrintWriter(String path)`. It seems to be handy for this scenario. However you maybe do not want to represent the path as `String`. Possibly the destination location is complex and relative, then a `File` would be more handy. Like `new File("testFile", directory)` which creates the file into the directory given as `File` with a relative path.

Just use the constructor which looks most handy for your current situation.

Comment: I understand everything what you say, and I agree.. this is what I knew myself. The question is, if I AM ABOUT to create a new file, and simply write into it, why shall I go through File object? - other cases are clear to me and of course, it can be that I receive File object from remote interface or etc... question was solely on creating new plain file and writing in it. I think in this latter case, simplified FileWriter is just a comfort made for developers.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is based on a architecture paradigm named [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

If you are just working on this specific case, it's simpler just do the second call and encapsulate two actions in one line. But in the software architecture point of view you are solving two different problems with one single operation.The first problem is to define and initialize the output. The second is to write to the choosed output.

This means that if in the future you want to change your application to work with differente outputs, like network connections, consoles or other, you will need to change the entire operation, because network connections can not be described as string, like files. But if you work with the Writer as a generic operation, that will always receive an initialized output stream, in the future you'll not need to make changes.

Your example is a simple case all this talk about software architecture may be a seen as a little complication. But as soon as you begin to work using this ideia of separation of concerns your code will be more consistent, maybe a little more verbose, but more robust.